# 301 redirect domain and all its pages

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have 2 sites on the same niche and basically with the same content, we are going to just close one of them and 301 everything to the one we will be keeping, content is basically the same the only difference is basically the url structure of some pages:

In the one to be 301:

> www.domaintobeclosed.com/browse-{keyword}-url string.html

In the one to be redirected to:

> www.domaintokeep.com/browse-url string.html

So here the only difference is that in the domain we are keeping the url structure doesnt have the keyword.

The other difference is that in single page url structure:

In the one to be 301:

> www.domaintobeclosed.com/title.html

in the one to be redirected to:

> www.domaintokeep.com/keyword/title.html

So the difference is that the domain to keep has a keyword before the actual title

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some real examples of old and new URLs.

Comment: for example:
http://www.documentalesonline.com/browse-documentales-de-biografias-videos-1-date.html
needs to be redirected to:
http://www.documaniatv.com/browse-biografias-videos-1-date.html

Comment: and 
http://www.documentalesonline.com/grandes-biografias-benjamin-franklin_dd41da120.html
needs to be redirected to:
http://www.documaniatv.com/biografias/grandes-biografias-benjamin-franklin-video_dd41da120.html

Comment: You can easily remove the keyword from the URL in the first example, but I have no way as to how you are going to insert a keyword that doesn't exist in one URL into the other short of writing a specific rewrite rule for each URL.

Answer (score 0):

So something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(browse)-keyword-(.*)$ http://www.domaintokeep.com/$1-$2
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/])\.html$ http://www.domaintokeep.com/keyword/$1.html
```